# mixed up on multiple hosts if one heavily in processing

Tags: apache, wamp, hosting, virtualhost, lamp

I use two different ports for hosting two similar sites (8082 for staging and 80 for production). Normally they are working fine in co-existence. However, when there is a heavy testing in staging site, somehow people in production get into the staging site. Can anyone point to me on where I might be wrong on my Apache setup? Thanks a lot.

I use WAMP from Bitnami (Apache 2.4).

in httpd.conf:

...

Listen 80

Listen 8082

ServerName localhost:80

DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/htdocs"

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

Require all granted
```

Include "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf"

...

In bitnami.conf:

NameVirtualHost *:80

DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/htdocs"

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride All

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  Order allow,deny                          
  Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
```

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)

Include "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"

NameVirtualHost *:8082

DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/htdocs"

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride All

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  Order allow,deny                          
  Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
```

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)

Include "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix2.conf"

...

In bitnami-apps-prefix.conf:

Include "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apps/sci02/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"

In bitnami-apps-prefix2.conf:

Include "D:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.4.40-0/apps/sci02/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"

where C: and D: goes to its real site configuration respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was not port mixing which I was misled. It was due to the mixing of environment variables (.env) which are used to define database, web title and others. Still don’t know why this happened, as each site has its own .env and normally they work properly. Anyway it can be resolved now via by-pass, i.e. directly set relevant variables in the application code not through .env.